# I have a filter to mark coincidences, but I would like to modify the way it is shown

Tags: angularjs

I currently have a text field that filters according to the matches, using the `title` or `name` keys. the filter highlights in yellow the words in which it finds matches by a text field. for example if there is a match by `name`, the `item.nombre` is highlighted.

[image]

[image]

```
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search">

  <ul>
    <!-- filter code -->
    <li ng-repeat="item in data ">
       <span ng-bind-html="item.title +' '+ item.name | highlight:search"></span>
        <!--
        I need this structure:
        <p><span>Title: </span><span>{{item.title}}</span></p>
        <p><span>Name: </span><span>{{item.name}}</span></p>-->

    </li>
  </ul>

$scope.data = [{
 title: "Bad",
 name: 'bill'
},
{
 title: "Good",
 name: 'Goe'
}]
```

This is my current code and it works.

```
$scope.data = [
    { text: "<< ==== Put text to Search ===== >>" }
  ];

$scope.data = [{
 title: "Bad",
 name: 'bill'
}, {
 title: "Good",
 name: 'Goe'
}, {
 title: "Great",
 name: 'Brad'
}, {
 title: "Cool",
 name: 'yan'
}, {
 title: "Excellent",
 name: 'mikle'
}, {
 title: "Awesome",
 name: 'mosa'
}, {
 title: "Horrible",
 name: 'morteza'
} ];

})
.filter('highlight', function($sce) {
    return function(text, phrase) {
      if (phrase) text = text.replace(new RegExp('('+phrase+')', 'gi'),
        '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>')

      return $sce.trustAsHtml(text)
    }
  });
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/GtOnj4KAkqv688PRSH0e?p=preview

The information shown to filter is this way:

```
<span ng-bind-html="item.title +' '+ item.name | highlight:search"></span>
```

and I would like to perform the same filter but under the following structure:

```
<p><span>Title: </span><span>{{item.title}}</span></p>
<p><span>Name: </span><span>{{item.name}}</span></p>
```

I would like it to be highlighted in yellow if there is a match in the text field to search, in the `title` or `name` keys but under my desired structure

and how could I do to hide objects that do not have coincidences? (currently all are shown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the following works:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in data">
  <p><span>Title: </span><span ng-bind-html="item.title | highlight:search"></span></p>
  <p><span>Name: </span><span ng-bind-html="item.name | highlight:search"></span></p>
</li>
```

Here's working example:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'World';

    $scope.data = [{
      text: "<< ==== Put text to Search ===== >>"
    }];

    $scope.data = [{
      title: "Bad",
      name: 'bill'
    }, {
      title: "Good",
      name: 'Goe'
    }, {
      title: "Great",
      name: 'Brad'
    }, {
      title: "Cool",
      name: 'yan'
    }, {
      title: "Excellent",
      name: 'mikle'
    }, {
      title: "Awesome",
      name: 'mosa'
    }, {
      title: "Horrible",
      name: 'morteza'
    }];

  })
  .filter('highlight', function($sce) {
    return function(text, phrase) {
      if (phrase) text = text.replace(new RegExp('(' + phrase + ')', 'gi'),
        '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>')

      return $sce.trustAsHtml(text)
    }
  });
```

```css
.highlighted {
  background: yellow
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.6" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <h1>Highlight text using AngularJS.</h1>

  <div class="container">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search">

    <ul>
      <!-- filter code -->
      <li ng-repeat="item in data">
        <p><span>Title: </span><span ng-bind-html="item.title | highlight:search"></span></p>
        <p><span>Name: </span><span ng-bind-html="item.name | highlight:search"></span></p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```